# get current page address with query string

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2, request, query-string

I know that current URI of page I can get by

```
#{request.requestURI}
```

it is in EL also available as follows:

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest()).getRequestURI();
```

Can i get current page address with query string at JSF page? How can i do this ?

For example for page with address in browser `/pages/work/myPage.xhtml?id=43&idLast=21`
I want to get String with `/pages/work/myPage.xhtml?id=43&idLast=21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) methods `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` and `HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`:

In EL that'd be:

```
#{request.requestURI}#{not empty request.queryString ? '?' : ''}#{request.queryString}"
```